# Any more elegant solution than provided for sorting tuple?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I was working on a somewhat gimmick problem in regard to tuples and finally solved it... but I felt that my coding is really ugly. Is there any pythonic/more simple way? Basically, the question gives you a tuple and that you need to sort tuple, remove numbers from same tuple, and then create an output like this.

OUTPUT = [this, sentence, should, now, make, sense]

At beginning, you have...

```
t=[(4,'make'),(1,'sentence'),(0,'this'),(3,'now'),(5,'sense'),(2,'should')]
```

My solution

```
t=[(4,'make'),(1,'sentence'),(0,'this'),(3,'now'),(5,'sense'),(2,'should')] 

def makeList(t):
    result = ''
    t.sort()
    for x, y in t:
        result += y +', '
    result = result[:-2]    
    result = ('[' + ', '.join([result]) + ']')
    return result 

OUTPUT: [this, sentence, should, now, make, sense]
```

Comment: You're aware that `some_string.join([single_element])` is equivalent to `single_element`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's easy:

```
sentence = [(4,'make'),(1,'sentence'),(0,'this'),(3,'now'),(5,'sense'),(2,'should')]
print "[%s]" % ', '.join(word for _,word in sorted(sentence))
```

There are several things to note here:

- A [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) is used as an argument to `join`. The syntax is the same as for [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- we iterate over the sorted list of tuples and use `_` to denote that we don't need the first value of the tuple (the number), but only the second part (the word)
- A [C-style format string](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) is used to build the final string with `[]` around it. We could also have used [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) here, but I think it looks cleaner this way (in this example)

Comment: +1. Explanation: the default sort order for tuples is [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: @larsmans: I assumed he had already understood that, because he uses this feature in his original code, too

Comment: @user1142285: Don't be. The constructs involved here need some getting used to to apply them efficiently. I added a small explanation in case you wonder how it works. Also, you are invited to accept this answer if you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to [Niklas Baumstark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865248/455276) correct answer:

```
>>> sentence = [(4,'make'),(1,'sentence'),(0,'this'),\
... (3,'now'),(5,'sense'),(2,'should')]
>>> [w for t,w in sorted(sentence)]
['this', 'sentence', 'should', 'now', 'make', 'sense']
```

(If you actually want a list than a string that just looks like a list...)